# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' flutter on api call

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart-null-safety, null-safety

Im using a service to create api from xml. This is my model file:

```js
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final economylistXml = economylistXmlFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

EconomylistXml economylistXmlFromJson(String str) => EconomylistXml.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String economylistXmlToJson(EconomylistXml data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class EconomylistXml {
  EconomylistXml({
    required this.haberler,
  });

  Haberler haberler;

  factory EconomylistXml.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => EconomylistXml(
    haberler: Haberler.fromJson(json["haberler"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "haberler": haberler.toJson(),
  };
}

class Haberler {
  Haberler({
    required this.haber,
  });

  List<Haber> haber;

  factory Haberler.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Haberler(
    haber: List<Haber>.from(json["haber"].map((x) => Haber.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "haber": List<dynamic>.from(haber.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Haber {
  Haber({
    required this.haberManset,
    required this.haberResim,
    required this.haberLink,
    required this.haberId,
    required this.haberVideo,
    required this.haberAciklama,
    required this.haberMetni,
    required this.haberKategorisi,
    required this.haberTarihi,
    required this.mansetResim,
    required this.izlesId,
    required this.yorumSay,
    required this.okunmaadedi,
    required this.anasayfamanset,
    required this.kategorimanset,
  });

  String haberManset;
  String haberResim;
  String haberLink;
  String haberId;
  String haberVideo;
  String haberAciklama;
  String haberMetni;
  HaberKategorisi? haberKategorisi;
  String haberTarihi;
  String mansetResim;
  String izlesId;
  String yorumSay;
  String okunmaadedi;
  String anasayfamanset;
  String kategorimanset;

  factory Haber.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Haber(
    haberManset: json["haber_manset"],
    haberResim: json["haber_resim"],
    haberLink: json["haber_link"],
    haberId: json["haber_id"],
    haberVideo: json["haber_video"],
    haberAciklama: json["haber_aciklama"],
    haberMetni: json["haber_metni"],
    haberKategorisi: haberKategorisiValues.map[json["haber_kategorisi"]],
    haberTarihi: json["haber_tarihi"],
    mansetResim: json["manset_resim"],
    izlesId: json["izles_id"],
    yorumSay: json["yorumSay"],
    okunmaadedi: json["okunmaadedi"],
    anasayfamanset: json["anasayfamanset"],
    kategorimanset: json["kategorimanset"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "haber_manset": haberManset,
    "haber_resim": haberResim,
    "haber_link": haberLink,
    "haber_id": haberId,
    "haber_video": haberVideo,
    "haber_aciklama": haberAciklama,
    "haber_metni": haberMetni,
    "haber_kategorisi": haberKategorisiValues.reverse[haberKategorisi],
    "haber_tarihi": haberTarihi,
    "manset_resim": mansetResim,
    "izles_id": izlesId,
    "yorumSay": yorumSay,
    "okunmaadedi": okunmaadedi,
    "anasayfamanset": anasayfamanset,
    "kategorimanset": kategorimanset,
  };
}

enum HaberKategorisi { EKONOMI, DNYA }

final haberKategorisiValues = EnumValues({
  "Dünya": HaberKategorisi.DNYA,
  "Ekonomi": HaberKategorisi.EKONOMI
});

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String>? reverseMap;

  EnumValues ( this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap!;
  }
}
```

and this is file where i call api

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:halkaarzhisseler/models/apis/economy_api.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../models/apis/economy_xml.dart';
import 'haberdetail.dart';


class Economy extends StatefulWidget {
  const Economy({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Economy> createState() => _EconomyState();
}

class _EconomyState extends State<Economy> {
  ScrollController? controller;
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final url = Uri.parse('https://v1.nocodeapi.com/miktadtahir/xml_to_json/htvLvoPDCwIEyTxa?url=https://www.trthaber.com/xml_mobile.php?tur=xml_genel&kategori=ekonomi&adet=20&selectEx=yorumSay,okunmaadedi,anasayfamanset,kategorimanset');
  var counter;
  EconomylistXml? haberResult;

  Future callHaber() async {
    try{

      final response = await http.get(url);

      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var haberler = economylistXmlFromJson(response.body);

        if(mounted);
        setState(() {
          haberResult = haberler;
        });
        return haberler;
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    callHaber();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
            'Ekonomi Haberleri'
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: counter != null ?

          ListView.builder(
              itemCount: counter,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(haberResult?.haberler.haber[index].haberManset??""),
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(haberResult?.haberler.haber[index].haberResim??""),),


                    onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HaberDetailScreen( subtitle: haberResult?.haberler.haber[index].haberMetni??"", title: haberResult?.haberler.haber[index].haberManset??"",image: haberResult?.haberler.haber[index].haberResim??"")),),
                  ),
                );
              }) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(

          )),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}



/*class Economy extends StatefulWidget {
  const Economy({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Economy> createState() => _EconomyState();
}

class _EconomyState extends State<Economy> {
  ScrollController? controller;
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final url = Uri.parse('https://api.collectapi.com/news/getNews?country=tr&tag=economy&padding=10');
  var counter;
  Economylist? haberResult;

  Future callHaber() async {
    try{
      Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'apikey 3fPhNZfVyrl8dOAkT86niI:3g2OzN57bil8vArOdVE3ka'
      };
      final response = await http.get(url,headers:requestHeaders);

      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var result = economylistFromJson(response.body);

        if(mounted);
        setState(() {
          counter = counter = result.result.length;
          haberResult = result;
        });
        return result;
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    callHaber();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
            'Ekonomi Haberleri'
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: counter != null ?

          ListView.builder(
              itemCount: counter,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(haberResult?.result[index].name??""),
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(haberResult?.result[index].image??""),),


                      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HaberDetailScreen( subtitle: haberResult?.result[index].description??"", title: haberResult?.result[index].name??"",image: haberResult?.result[index].image??"")),),
                  ),
                );
              }) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(

          )),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}

 */
```

I'm getting this error on console : type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' and CircularProgressIndicator working continuously. How can i fix this?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you include your json response

Comment: In your `Haberler` class are all attributes not nullable. This leads to the mentioned error, if there is one of your String attributes null in your response. Check the response and search for the null value.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh  when i check the response i see that izlesid and haberviod sometimes returns null. how can i add this to model?

Comment: @MCB izlesid and habervideo sometimes returns null

Comment: Better make fields nullable or while reading data doing null check and providing default value on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handle null value it is better to make variable nullable data on entities

```dart
class Haber {
  String? haberManset;
  String? haberResim;
  String? haberLink;
```

Or provide empty string on null case while reading JSON

```dart
  haberVideo: json["haber_video"]??"", //this
  izlesId: json["izles_id"]??"",
```

Comment: Only loads CircularProgressIndicator no error in console or anywhere. How it could be? –

Comment: Do you get any error message on `print(e.toString());`

Comment: Nothing happens. just CircularProgressIndicator working

Comment: Can you try using `FutureBuilder`

Comment: Can you write code sample when I ask a question?

Comment: @Yasin Sheikh I mean if i ask this as a new question

Comment: I will try give a try, also it would be easier for others if you could include JSON response as well or the API if it is public

Answer (score 0):

You can make `response != null` to the top. And check the debug console for the response. Probably you get some other exception like socket exception.

```dart
 try{

      final response = await http.get(url);
if(response != null){ //this line you need to add
 if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var haberler = economylistXmlFromJson(response.body);

        if(mounted);
        setState(() {
          haberResult = haberler;
        });
        return haberler;
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
}else{
//stop indicator in here if response is null
//you're code in here
}
      
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Change String to String? at not required fields:

```
class Haber {
  Haber({
    required this.haberManset,
    required this.haberResim,
    required this.haberLink,
    required this.haberId,
    required this.haberVideo,
    required this.haberAciklama,
    required this.haberMetni,
    required this.haberKategorisi,
    required this.haberTarihi,
    required this.mansetResim,
    required this.izlesId,
    required this.yorumSay,
    required this.okunmaadedi,
    required this.anasayfamanset,
    required this.kategorimanset,
  });

  String haberManset;
  String haberResim;
  String haberLink;
  String haberId;
  String? haberVideo; //<-- here
  String haberAciklama;
  String haberMetni;
  HaberKategorisi? haberKategorisi;
  String haberTarihi;
  String mansetResim;
  String? izlesId; //<-- and here
  String yorumSay;
  String okunmaadedi;
  String anasayfamanset;
  String kategorimanset;

  factory Haber.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Haber(
    haberManset: json["haber_manset"],
    haberResim: json["haber_resim"],
    haberLink: json["haber_link"],
    haberId: json["haber_id"],
    haberVideo: json["haber_video"],
    haberAciklama: json["haber_aciklama"],
    haberMetni: json["haber_metni"],
    haberKategorisi: haberKategorisiValues.map[json["haber_kategorisi"]],
    haberTarihi: json["haber_tarihi"],
    mansetResim: json["manset_resim"],
    izlesId: json["izles_id"],
    yorumSay: json["yorumSay"],
    okunmaadedi: json["okunmaadedi"],
    anasayfamanset: json["anasayfamanset"],
    kategorimanset: json["kategorimanset"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "haber_manset": haberManset,
    "haber_resim": haberResim,
    "haber_link": haberLink,
    "haber_id": haberId,
    "haber_video": haberVideo,
    "haber_aciklama": haberAciklama,
    "haber_metni": haberMetni,
    "haber_kategorisi": haberKategorisiValues.reverse[haberKategorisi],
    "haber_tarihi": haberTarihi,
    "manset_resim": mansetResim,
    "izles_id": izlesId,
    "yorumSay": yorumSay,
    "okunmaadedi": okunmaadedi,
    "anasayfamanset": anasayfamanset,
    "kategorimanset": kategorimanset,
  };
}
```

Comment: Only loads CircularProgressIndicator no error in console or anywhere. How it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 class Haber {
      String haberManset = "";
      String haberResim = "";
      String haberLink = ""
```

or

```
  haberVideo: json["haber_video"].toString(), 
  izlesId: json["izles_id"].toString(),
```